# Rufus Damaged my Pendrive

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, rufus

I was using Rufus (on Windows 10, Laptop) to create a bootable Windows 7 USB installer. Then bootable process has been completed successfully. But when I tried to boot it on another PC (Desktop) it won't boot. Even no USB has been detected. Now this pendrive can't be shown on any computer.
Is it possible to fix this?

Edit: The USB drive doesn't show up in Disk management. In Disk manager it shows "Disk 2, Removeable (H):, No media).

Comment: They're not usually worth the effort once they start to error. Just bin it & get a new one.

Comment: It is very unlikely the software itself caused this hardware failure.  Hardware failures are very rarely caused by software.  Be sure you try more than a single machine before you toss the drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rufus Damaged my USB. Windows can not detect USB](https://superuser.com/questions/663942/rufus-damaged-my-usb-windows-can-not-detect-usb)

Comment: Not duplicate. My pendrive shown in Disk Management. Shows only drive letter but shows "No media".

Comment: Sometimes formatting can cause a usb stick to become unusable or unformatable again. When this happens if in Windows I can always get it to reformat in Linux or vice versa where it works again. So maybe try a live cd of Ubuntu or Fedora and try to format it again. If that won't work then see if its still under warranty.

Comment: DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

Virtual Disk Service error:
There is no media in the device.


DISKPART>

When i try to format USB through CMD this is shown.