# USB disk always mounted as offline. Anything that I can do about this?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

My 2 TB 2.5" USB 3.0 external disk is never found by my TV. When I plug it to my Windows 10 Pro, it is mounted properly (Disk Management can see it), but "offline" (i.e. without any letter assigned to it):

[image]

Is there any specific thing (like file system, disk feature, boot record type etc.) that is causing this?

Is there anything that I can do to have this disk accessible (i.e. under drive letter) every time, I connect it to my PC's USB port (and not being forced to rush to Disk Management to manually assign a letter to it each time; as I do right now)?

Of course, is there anything that I can do [except formatting the disk](https://superuser.com/a/1512751/156554), because in contains a 2 TB of data that cannot be lost.

Comment: Can't you assign a drive letter to it as instructed? If not maybe there's something wrong with the partition table (e.g. messed up partition type code).

Comment: @TomYan Of course I can! :) I just don't want to do this each and every time I plug out and plug in the disk again.

Comment: Do the tricks [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/117336-enable-disable-automount-new-disks-drives-windows.html) work? Also try "scrubbing" `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` manually (as in, remove *all* items except `(Default)` in it) and reboot and see, perhaps. (Normally it won't break anything.)

Comment: Also try clearing the `nodefaultdriveletter` attribute for the corresponding volume: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attributes-volume

Comment: @TomYan The `automount enable` did the trick. Care to craft an answer so I can accept it and bring you the rep? Thank you.