# Can Rufus damage a device? No media + is not accessible A device which does not exist was specified

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, mbr

I used Rufus 3.15p to create an MBR bootable Windows 7 installer. An error occurred while the Rufus was copying the ISO file. Now the flash USB (SanDisk 8GB) does not work! In CMD Disk part shows "no media" instead of "online". Windows disk manager shows an empty disk with no media. In file manager just show a drive. Once I click on it, it shows "is not accessible A device which does not exist was specified". In properties, it doesn't show sizes and its partition style is MBR. Also, I cannot run check disk for this drive.

These solutions did not work for me:

- Assigning another label.
- Chkdsk
- Rebuild MBR of my internal disk with easeUS.
- DISKPART (clean and repartitioning)
- Disk Manager (nothing for partitioning or formatting)
- Reinstalling its driver
- HDD LLF Low Level Format Tool (did not detect its disk)
- PartitionWizard (did not detect it)

Can Rufus incomplete process cause the damage? Do you have any solution to fix the USB flash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rufus Damaged my USB. Windows can not detect USB](https://superuser.com/questions/663942/rufus-damaged-my-usb-windows-can-not-detect-usb)

Comment: The solutions in the post do not work for me. Besides, I am not sure that the asker's problem was exactly matched with my problem "No media"

Comment: `Rufus is dangerous or not?` .. probably not even though it isn't what I would recommend for doing this task.  Rufus rocks. :) .. but the windows media tool is what I would use for this specific task.  Check out the link that @Silbee provided.  USB tragically die all of the time and also end up in states that require lower level tools to fix (if they can be fixed at all).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas , As you can guess, if I used windows media tool, the USB flash would not damaged. I've checked that post; the solutions do not work for my case, as the question also has not an accepted answer.

Comment: I suggest you stop trying to blame one specific software. Writing lots of stuff to a USB flash drive is simply that much more likely to kill the drive than day-to-day use with smaller files. Now your flash drive is dead. Get over it and get a new one. Rufus is not to blame.

Comment: It's a technical question. There is no blame here! I think your answer is get a new one. Good but more technical answers are required.

Answer (score 2):

As Rufus is just writing sectors to a device there is no chance for Rufus to damage it.
With Rufus being typically used to write ISO files (disk images) to flash drives it puts the drive under an above average load.
There is no issue with excessive wear when doing that.
But there is a higher probability of pre-existing errors being disclosed because a lot of sectors are being touched in a short period of time.